# How to ignore a specific exception from UI?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

How can I let current Spring application to ignore a specific exception class (say NoUIException or `OptimisticLockingException`) on the UI but not affect the logging? I know `org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver` can map certain exception with an UI request but don't know how to avoid one on UI.

## UPDATE

I do some study from Spring web site and come with following solution, I tried but it does not work

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionControllerAdvice {

    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
    @ExceptionHandler(org.apache.openjpa.persistence.OptimisticLockException.class)
    public void optimisticLockExceptionHandler() {
        // do nothing, just ignore the exception
        logger.info("yeah...no exception I hope !!!");
    }
}
```

## UPDATE2

I am not sure if it is relevant but I have register `SimpleMappingExceptionResolver` in the mvc config context

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver" p:defaultErrorView="uncaughtException">
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
        <props>
            <prop key=".DataAccessException">dataAccessFailure</prop>
            <prop key=".AccessDeniedException">accessDenied</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Is there any way `SimpleMappingExceptionResolver` may have conflict to the `controller advisor`?

Answer (score 0):

The exception handler is called by an *HandlerExceptionResolver* called *ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver*.

Make sure that you have properly configured component scanning; the package containing your advice must be scanned. Don't forget to enable annotations.

In Spring XML:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.foo.bar" />
<mvc:annotation-driven>
```

In Spring boot, uses @ComponentScan (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html). Then you have to extend the class *WebMvcConfigurerAdapter* and specify your resolvers. Those resolvers are put in an *HandlerExceptionResolverComposite*. The first resolver that returns a non-null model and view wins.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to display error page for particular exception then catch that exception with catch block and don't re-throw any Application specific exception.